# Can't list all my application in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5

I use the following code to list all my applications in the App Store.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/AbcCompany"]];
```

It works fine on iOS 4.3 but lists nothing on iOS 5. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "lists nothing"? Does the App Store give an error or does it show your company name with an empty list?

Comment: It do launch the AppStore program, but it shows "Item Not Found".

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether apple approve that apps, if it approved  app means then only you can see on iTunes before that it does not open.

Please follow this structure:
itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-app-name-is-new/id389921?mt=8
If you need further information contact me

Comment: Hi maheswaran, I think it is nothing to do with apps. It works properly in iOS 4.2/4.3, but can not work on iOS 5. I have been changing "AbcCompany" to "Gameloft", but it got the same result.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, so make sure the link of your apps, and update with that link, for the easy way, go to itunes in system and right click your app and then copy link then paste it works.